# read file from inside jar Not Working

Tags: java, jar, io, inputstream, embedded-resource

In Java, I have tried the different techniques of reading a file inside the jar. I have gotten one to work inside another program, but not this one. The InputStream that I get from the classname.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filenamestring); method returns null.

```
 package mainpkg;

 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.UIManager;

 public class MainClass extends JFrame{
JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
boolean isInstalling = false;
public MainClass(){
    super("StringThatTitleWillBe");
}
public void initiate(){
    setLookAndFeel();
    setSize(550, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout bl = new GridLayout(2, 1, 10, 10);
    setLayout(bl);

    JButton b = new JButton("Install");
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if(!isInstalling){
            isInstalling = true;
            install();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

    });
    add(b);
    jtf.setEditable(false);
    add(jtf);
    //show
    setVisible(true);
}
private void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.print("failed to load look and feel");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    MainClass m = new MainClass();
    m.initiate();
}

public void install() {
    String files = "name of jarfile inside the jar to be read";
    InputStream stream = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(files);
    File f = new File(files);
    if(stream == null)
        System.out.println("stream is null");
    try {
        int val = stream.read();
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        while(val != -1){
        br.write(val);
        val = stream.read();
        }
        stream.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    isInstalling = false;
     }
 }
```

It Prints "stream is null" and gives an error on the line: stream.read();
I know that means that the file is not being converted to an InputStream properly.
Have I made a stupid mistake??? please help. Thanks in advance
Edit: the file that I want to copy in the same directory as the jar is directly inside the jar. It is not in a package or any such additional directory.

Comment: All the GUI code is completely irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: One cannot establish a `File` that points to a resource in a Jar.  Archives don't contain any files.  They do however contain resources that can be accessed by `URL` or `InputStream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `getResourceAsStream(String)` returns `null`, that means that the class loader can't find a resource with the name you gave it.  Either it is plain wrong, or maybe you have used a relative name and the resource isn't in the "/" directory in the JAR.

For details, read the javadoc for [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), paying careful attention to:

- the value returned, and
- the handling of relative pathnames (follow the `getResource` link!!).

If you want to load a resource using a relative name that is resolved relative the classes package, you should write this:

```
    MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(files);
```

The `Class.getResource...` methods resolve relative names relative to the class.  So the above would resolve `"foo.txt"` to `"/mainpkg/foo.txt"` ... where your version would resolve it to `"/foo.txt"`.

Comment: the file is directly in the project folder, and I tried the / before it but it still did not work. It worked in my other project without the slash, and the file was in the /foo.txt, so I don't understand what I am supposed to do to make it work for the second project. Thanks for your idea though, its probably that I referenced it incorrectly. I tried adding / and \\ before it but neither worked

Comment: I figured out InputStream stream = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(files); was my only option, and i had to put the jar in that package. none of the other options were working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> I know that means that the file is not being converted to an InputStream properly

No it doesn't. It means that the resource named was not found. Check the Javadoc.

Then check the resource name, which you have helpfully omitted from your post, against a listing of the JAR.

If 'stream' is null you have no business continuing on with trying to read it and getting an NPE. This is just poor programming.

Also, a resource inside a JAR file is not a File, and constructing a File with its name is a meaningless activity.

Comment: sorry for the miscommunication. The file is directly inside the jar. I set the filename to "filename.extension". Do I need to add "\\" in front of it? I was trying to get the file inside the jar, and copy it into the same directory the jar is in

Comment: @user2016463 You need to add "/" in front of it.